# How to do the prediction with text mining and rating score?

Tags: data-mining

I have the data as following:

```
rating  document1    document2
5       some words   some words
3       some words   some words
2       some words   some words
```

First column is user rating, and other two are the user feedback, which is a cocument. Also, i have `category` is a list of -1 and 1, which stands for negative and positive for each row.

I would like to do the prediction for the `category`. I think about document-term matrix, then ,I do not know how to also involve the rating in the prediction? Is there anyone can guide me ? Thanks so much!

Comment: You are trying to predict category (+1 or -1) from ratings and words (called documents).  You seem to be stuck on how to use the ratings to predict category.  Have you considered plotting the data to see if there is any apparent relationship between rating and category?  You seem not to be stuck on how to use the words to predict the category.  That seems more difficult.  How are you doing that?

Comment: @JoelW. I can do either rating with category or words with category. My problem is I do not know how to predict category on both rating and document. I did txt mining with document-term matrix.

Comment: Can you say that differently? I do not understand what you wrote.